# Why IMutableEntityType.BaseType is null for entities that inherit directly from a base class?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

I've defined the following classes:

```
public class DeletableEntity
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : DeletableEntity
{
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{        
}
```

In the OnModelCreating I'm getting only entities that inherit from DeletableEntity like this:

```
    foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if (typeof(DeletableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType) == true)
        {
            var et = entityType.BaseType;
        }
    }
```

Interestingly ClassA has entityType.BaseType == null but ClrType.BaseType clearly shows ClassA inherits from DeletableEntity:

[image]:

For ClassB entityType.BaseType is ClassA as expected:

[image]

Why first successor's parent class is being ignored? Is this by design?

PS: I'm using EF Core 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there is a difference between base *class* and base *entity*.

`IEntityType` represents class mapped as EF Core *entity*. The type `BaseType` property of `IEnityType` is also `IEnityType`. But in your example `DeletableEntity` is just a base class, not a base entity, so the property returns `null`.

Probably the best explanation is the property declaration:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets the base type of the entity. Returns null if this is not a derived type
//     in an inheritance hierarchy.
IEntityType BaseType { get; }
```

where "inheritance hierarchy" refers to EF [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance):

> Inheritance in the EF model is used to control how inheritance in the entity classes is represented in the database.

and also [Inheritance (Relational Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance).